# Running Selenium on NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my first attempt with `selenium-webdriver` on `NodeJs` in `Windows 7` environment. Here is what I have done to try to make it work:

1. Installed `NodeJs 7.5` (officially supported by Selenium as noted on their Git https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver)
2. Installed `selenium-webdriver` using `npm`
3. Downloaded `chromedriver.exe 2.27` to `"C:\Selenium Utilities\chromedriver"`
4. Added `chromedriver` to my `PATH` as `C:\Selenium Utilities\chromedriver;`
5. Added my first test from Selenium Git page:

   ```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
           By = webdriver.By, until = webdriver.until;

   var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
       .forBrowser('chrome')
       .build();

   driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
   driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
   driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
   driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
   driver.quit();
   ```
6. Tried running test via `node test.js`

As a result, I get error saying (excerpts):

> "...throw new Error('Do not know how to build driver: ' + browser"
>
> "Error: Do not know how to build driver: C; did you forget to call
>   usingServer(url)?"

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to run a separate Selenium server in order to run this?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looked fine to me, so I ran it to check that. I can confirm it [runs fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3y6a1xxt9v1y41/webdriver.mov?dl=0) (on macOS Sierra). [Here's a link to the repo I created](https://github.com/Obehave-testing/42473195-running-selenium-on-nodejs).

It looks like you might need to extend the wait for the page title though, sometimes I found loading Google's page title took longer than a second.

Another option would be to try a hosted service, rather than setting up your own selenium server. There are a variety available, I've just made [Obehave](https://wwww.obehave.io) for exactly this purpose. There is zero setup required - you can start writing your tests straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Install the chromedriver via npm.

```
npm install chromedriver --save-dev
```

Then add chrome on top of the js:

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
```

Finally script:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By, until = webdriver.until;
        var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr').then(function(){
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();
    driver.quit();
});
```

Comment: why `var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome)' if its never used?

Answer (score 1):

chrome driver version and installed chrome must be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "SELENIUM_BROWSER" variable from environment variables or add quotes its path.

> "Error: Do not know how to build driver: **C**; did you forget to call usingServer(url)?"

C letter in the error is the first letter of C:\ in the path of the SELENIUM_BROWSER variable.